# WPF - Refresh a OneTime binding on ObjectModel change without VIewModel (datacontext) changing

Tags: wpf, binding-mode

I have a ViewModel that is set up when my window opens up. After the user looks up something from the database, the view model sets the objectmodel from the result, which then notifies all the display items to update.

Here is general setup:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    
    public ObjectModel {get;set;} // Raises PropertyChanged using String.Empty to notify all controls the object has changed
    
    Properties....
    Commands....

    LookupMethod() => ObjectModel = SearchDatabase(SearchTerm); //
}

//This is a custom control that I have working already
public class CustomNumericUpDown
{
   public int DefaultValue {get;set;} // This value sohuld be set any time the objectmodel updates
   public int Value {get;set;} // Value specified by user

    // If Value != DefaultValue, the background color is updated to show that value was altered
}


XAML for the custom control within the parent window:

<CC:NumericUpDown 
    x:Name="Axis_Z_Stroke" 
    Value="{Binding ObjectModel.AxisInfo.Axis_Z.StrokeLimit, Mode=OneWay}" 
    DefaultValue="{Binding Path=ObjectModel.AxisInfo.Axis_Z.StrokeLimit, Mode=OneTime
    }"/>
```

The problem with this is that the 'DefaultValue' property only updates when the form first loads, so the 'defaultvalue' is always set to 0, instead of whatever the initial property of the objectmodel is.

Other than hard coding the parent window to use `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()` against every one of these controls when the objectmodel is updated, is there a way to set that value?

( I suppose I could create a slew of the 'defaultvalue' properties within my viewmodel that are updated when the objectmodel itself is updated, but if this can be avoided I'd prefer it)

I already looked into writing an attached method or property to try and get this to work, but couldn't figure out how. And since `UpdateTargetTrigger` is simply not a thing, I'm unsure about how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

After writing my post, I realize how to do it. After a few quick tests, this worked perfectly for what I wanted to do:

```
<CC:NumericUpDown x:Name="Axis_Z_Stroke" 
DataContext="{Binding ObjectModel}" 
Value="{Binding AxisInfo.Axis_Z.StrokeLimit, Mode=OneWay}" 
DefaultValue="{Binding Path=AxisInfo.Axis_Z.StrokeLimit, Mode=OneTime}"
/>
```

Since the DataContext of the parent doesn't actually change, but the ObjectModel does, I specified the DataContext of the control itself, binding it to the `ObjectModel` property of the parent control.

Now, since the DataContext for this control has been updated here, it forces the `OneTime` binding to update.

Even better though, since this is particular control is housed within a grid within a parent control, I set the top-level grid's data context. SO now everything in the grid is updated when that changes, and the windows that display the overall control can simply provide the correct viewmodel